# "cut down on" vs "cut down"

Tags: phrase-choice

Those phrases are pretty similar. I often hear people say "cut down on sugar/coffee/soda/ (anything related to food) ". But in other contexts, are those phrases interchangeable?

For example:

> The country cut down on waste production last year.
>   The country cut down waste production last year.

Are both phrases correct in that sentence?

Comment: "Cut down on" means _reduce the consumption of,_  and your first example is idiomatic. _Cut down_ (without _on_) would be grammatically correct, but not idiomatic. Note that _cut down_ also may refer to the physical act of _cutting_ something down (most often trees.)

Comment: We are always happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

You definitely cut down trees, but "cut down waste production" doesn't sound right to me. You may simply "cut waste production" though...

"Cut down" something to me is literal: you are cutting something so that it falls over. "Cut down on" something is the idiom that you gave.